# How can I deserialize multiple variants of a struct based on the value of a tag inside the struct itself using serde/quick-xml?

Tags: xml, rust, serde, serde-json

I am using quick_xml to deserialize some xml into their respective structs. I have implemented a enum variant and have implemented Deserialize myself for the enum. I would like to deserialize the enum based on the value in one of the tags inside the struct. The deserialized structs should contain this tag/value as an attribute as well. The limitation I have is that a deserializer does not implement copy or clone so I cannot use it to deserialize a struct more than once. The approach I have taken below is to deserialize the tag into a struct and then call deserialize based on the value of that tag which is obviously not working. Also, deserialize is derived for the structs I am trying to deserialize to.

Any suggestions/help on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a small snippet of the code implementing deserialize for my enum:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Serialize)]
pub enum XMLDocumentVersion {
    XMLDocumentVersion01(xml_document_version_01::XMLDocumentVersion01),
    XMLDocumentVersion03(xml_document_version_03::XMLDocumentVersion03),
    XMLDocumentVersion05(xml_document_version_05::XMLDocumentVersion05)
}


impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for XMLDocumentVersion {

    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where
            D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
        struct Meta{
            #[serde(
                alias = "version",
                deserialize_with = "deserialization_functions::string_is_capitalized_and_empty_string_is_none",
                default
            )]
            version: Option<String>
        }
        
        let meta: Meta = Meta::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let version = meta.version;

        if version.is_none(){
            //deserialize using oldest schema version
            let document = xml_document_version_01::XMLDocumentVersion01::deserialize(deserializer)?;
            return Ok(XMLDocumentVersion::XMLDocumentVersion01(document));
        }

        else if let Some("01") = version.as_deref(){
            let document = xml_document_version_01::XMLDocumentVersion01::deserialize(deserializer)?;
            return Ok(XMLDocumentVersion::XMLDocumentVersion01(document));
        }

        else if let Some("03") = version.as_deref() {
            let document = xml_document_version_03::XMLDocumentVersion03::deserialize(deserializer)?;
            return Ok(XMLDocumentVersion::XMLDocumentVersion03(document));
        }

        // more code/cases...

        else {
        // don't have a variant for the schema version so deserialize using newest schema version
            let document = xml_document_version_05::XMLDocumentVersion05::deserialize(deserializer)?;
            return Ok(XMLDocumentVersion::XMLDocumentVersion05(document));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a small sample xml sample/structure I am trying to deserialize to get the general idea. It is not the actual xml.

Variant 1:

```
<document>

<version>01</version>

<type>8</type>

<period>2021-12-21</period>

<issuer>
    <id>7983</id>
    <name>Jane Al</name>
    <marker>JRJ</marker>
</issuer>

--...many more tags completely different from tags in other variant, different names and nesting structure
</document>
```

Variant 2:

```
<document>

<version>03</version>

<type>7</type>

<period>2021-12-21</period>

<alloc>rEsJ<alloc>
    
<issuer>
    <id>7983</id>
    <name>Jane Al</name>
    <marker>JRJ</marker>
</issuer>

--...many more tags completely different from tags in other variant, different names and nesting structure

</document>
```

EDIT:

I got the idea to serialize to a basic struct and then conditionally deserialize. However, even deserializing to a basic structure is giving me errors. Here are 2 versions one with deserialize manually implemented and there other where it is derived:

This gives me error `Some(Start)`

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Serialize)]
struct Doc{
    contents: String
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Doc {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where
            D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let val: String = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        return Ok(Doc{contents: val});
    }
}

let doc = Doc::deserialize(deserializer)?;
println!("{:?}", doc.clone());
let val = doc.contents;
```

This gives me error `duplicate field \$value\`

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    struct Doc{
        #[serde(rename ="$value")]
        contents: String
    }

let doc = Doc::deserialize(deserializer)?;
println!("{:?}", doc.clone()); 
let val = doc.contents;
```

Comment: I think this is essentially an ["internally tagged" enum in serde terms](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged).

Comment: This doesn't work, it finds the variant but it gives error "invalid type: map, expected a string" on a variant match. I am not sure why this is. For additional context, the "version" tag which we use to match the variant is an attribute in each variant that should be deserialized. Also , the other tags are at the same level as the "version" tag in the structs as you can see from the xml samples. Also, I need to be able to define a default variant if the tag is not present and a default variant if the tag is present but no variant matches the tag.

Comment: I think you will need to use a custom deserializer, or use something besides serde for this case.